# How can I get the value of a windows registry key in windows 10 with batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I am trying to find the proxy configuration through running a .bat file, but it's not returning the value

```
@echo OFF

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set VALUE_NAME=ProxyEnable

FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=1-3" %%A IN ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul') DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueType=%%B
    set ValueValue=%%C
)

if defined ValueName (
    @echo Value Name = %ValueName%
    @echo Value Type = %ValueType%
    @echo Value Value = %ValueValue%
) else (
    @echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
)
```

Could you please let me know what mistakes I am doing here.

Comment: `reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit `usebackq`, change `skip=4` to `skip=2` and it should be working